# Clicking and clicking noise with bench presses

Tags: exercise, weightlifting, bodybuilding, flexibility, upper-body-workout

When doing bench presses, both the left and right areas of my shoulders make this really loud clicking sound and it feels as if the bones are clicking against each other.  This has been happening for a few months now.  I thought it would go away, however it remains exactly the same.

Any thoughts would be appreciated, thanks!

Comment: That ain't right... but I think more information would be helpful to diagnose. Is there any pain when this happens? Is it possible to get a friend to record a video clip of you doing a press and post that so that we can diagnose technique? I suspect that if there isn't an obvious flaw in your technique, then seeing a dr. might be the way to go.

Comment: I think this question should be closed, because any advice given on the subject could be bad for the person in question. Also, this question (if it can be called so), asks for a discussion, rather than a concise answer.

Comment: @Janis Peiseniek : disagree, some of us here might have some good advice from personal experience on the matter - however, it should include a disclaimer saying to always seek proper medical advice

Comment: @bguiz, agreed.  I'm not looking for medical advice per say.  Any experience from people who may be or may have experienced the same.

Comment: More general discussion of the matter on meta.fitness http://bit.ly/eyfaaO

Answer (score 5):

You are probably lowering the barbell too high up your chest which causes your elbows to flare out.  Try moving the barbell lower down your chest on the way down so you can keep your elbows more tucked in (perhaps < 45 degrees to your body instead of 90).  This will make sure the bench press is a chest and arm workout and not a dangerous shoulder workout.

Obviously its impossible to know if you are doing this without seeing your technique, try an empty barbell at the gym next time and get someone to watch your elbow position.

Answer (score 3):

I think there is just one advice that can be given in this case:

***See a doctor!***

Anything else would be plain bad for you. This is something that cannot be answered correctly without a physical exam.

It is clear, that this "clicking" is not something that should be happening normally and should be taken care of by a professional.